# dex2oat64 is eating battery on Android 12 (Beta). What is it?

Tags: battery, google-pixel, android-beta-program, android-12

I have updated my Pixel 5 to Android 12 Beta, and in the last update, the "app" or service called "dex2oat64" eats too much battery.

[image]

I found some [thread in Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/android_beta/comments/o0q1hi/dex2oat64_battery_usege/), but they also don't know the answers like me.

What is this app/service?

Comment: dex2oat compiles the Java byte code to native ARM code so applications will run faster. After each update/upgrade all aps are usually processed one time this way which can take several minutes and a significant amount of battery.

Comment: @Robert That sounds like a good answer.  Why only posted as a comment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

dex2oat is a utility used when installing or updating applications, so that was likely just a remnant of your "Android is upgrading" phase that you saw after the initial/first reboot after the system/software update.

Most likely you have just installed Android 12 and it's setting up everything/caching process in the background. See if it get fixed in a few days (3-4 days usually).